# Deploy Web Part from Visual Studio to remote SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, visual-web-part, farm-solution

I've made a Visual Web Part in Visual Studio (non-sandboxed) that I could easily deploy & "debug" on my local SharePoint installation.

I want to copy this web part to another SharePoint installation, so I went ahead and right-clicked the project in Visual Studio, clicked on the Publish, and saved it to the drive. I got a **.wsp** file.

I've taken this .wsp file and copied to the other server, installed with **Add-SPSolution** & **Install-SPSolution**

I don't see the web part in the Web Part gallery.

How can I get it there? What steps am I missing?

Comment: did you deploy it to the GAC?

Install-SPSolution -Identity your_solution.wsp -GACDeployment

Comment: A simliar question has been asked, and may help you:
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79186/deployed-web-parts-dont-show-up-in-web-part-gallery

Answer (score 0):

In addition to add/install the WSP package, you need to activate the feature that contains the Web part on each site collection you want it.

Open your site collection root in a browser, go to "Site settings", "Site collection features" and activate your feature. After that, your Web part should be provisionned and visible in the WP galery.